# Merge Statement in SQL Statement Add, Update, Delete in single SP

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

I am trying to create merge statement to do `Insert, Update, Delete` in one SP as below.

But my requirement is while inserting statement I need to add multiple insert with different values and facing issue in that.
Will Delete Statement work or do I need to change it?

```
Declare @Project_Id INT =12;
MERGE Table1 AS TARGET
USING Table2 AS SOURCE 
ON (TARGET.Id = SOURCE.Id AND TARGET.Project_Id = SOURCE.Project_Id)

--When records are matched, update the records if there is any change
WHEN MATCHED AND TARGET.Name <> SOURCE.Name AND TARGET.Project_Id = @Project_Id 
THEN UPDATE SET TARGET.Name = SOURCE.Name, Target.Project_Id= @Project_Id

--When no records are matched, insert the incoming records from source table to target table
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
THEN 
   INSERT  (project_id,Financials_Desc,created_date,createdby,Name,Id) Values 
   (@PROJECT_ID,'Gross Sales (or BGA) Total - Launch 
   Year',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,@createdby,Source.Name,Source.Id )
   INSERT  (project_id,Financials_Desc,created_date,createdby,Name,Id) Values 
   (@PROJECT_ID,'Gross Sales (or BGA) Total - 
   Ongoing',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,@createdby,Source.Name,Source.Id )


   --When there is a row that exists in target and same record does not exist in source then delete 
   this record target
   WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE 
   THEN DELETE
```

Answer (score 0):

In the source field you can use a query, if I was you I  would merge the destination with a query that represent the final result of the merge:

```
MERGE Table1 AS TARGET
USING (select value, value from tableX join tableY ...) AS SOURCE
```

Also, be aware that when comparing the matched results you need to account for null values:

```
when matched and (source.val != target.val or source.val is null and target.val is not null or source.val is not null and target.val is null)
```